# Determine the sequences related to a given table name PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to write a function to determine the sequences related to a given table name, in the query within the function, I went with something like this:

```
    select s.relname as sec from pg_class s 
    join pg_depend d on d.objid=s.oid and d.classid='pg_class'::regclass 
    and d.refclassid='pg_class'::regclass 
    join pg_class t on t.oid=d.refobjid 
    join pg_namespace n on n.oid=t.relnamespace 
    join pg_attribute a on a.attrelid=t.oid and a.attnum=d.refobjsubid 
    where s.relkind='S' and t.relname = 'table_name'
```

However it doesn't seem to find all the sequences that exists, i.e. for some tables, it just doesn't find the related sequences, but for certain ones it does.

Comment: Keep in mind that sequences are related to tables when they are created by `IDENTITY` or `SERIAL` columns only. Other sequences can be related to multiple tables or none at all.

Comment: for those columns where your query doesn't return something, you can cross check using `pg_get_serial_sequence()`. But maybe you didn't make the columns "own" the sequence

Comment: maybe it's related with sequence ownership ? https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Fixing_Sequences

Comment: Yes, indeed it was an ownership problem. Now that I modified some things, it works perfectly. Thank you guys